# How to wrap each text and link with <li> by jquery after iterate in all text and links inside td

Tags: jquery, html

I know how to get text and html of `td` after iterate. This way we can do so:

```
$("#test tr.webgrid-footer td").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

but I am facing an error when I am trying to do this:

HTML looks like:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr class="webgrid-footer">
    <td colspan="6">
      1
      <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=2&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">2</a>
      <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=3&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">3</a>
      <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">4</a>
      <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=2&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true"><img src="/images/next.png"></a>
      <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true"><img src="/images/last.png"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I want my html to look like below, where the text and links are wrapped within `<li>`.

```
<ul class="paginate pag1 clearfix">
  <li class="single">Page 1 of 5</li>
  <li class="current">1</li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=2&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=3&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="index-2.html">next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please tell me how to iterate in all text and links in `td` of `tr` having class name `webgrid-footer` by jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First get all of the links & text nodes:**

```
var $elements = $('.webgrid-footer td')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 || this.nodeType === 1; // 1 means elements, 3 means text node
  });
```

**then, create your 'ul' element:**

```
var $list = $('<ul />');
```

**no iterate over the list of nodes, create an `li` element for each of them:**

```
$elements.each(function(){
    var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));
    $list.append($item);
});
```

**Now your `$list` object should look like you wanted, inject it to the right place...**

```
$('body').append($list);
```

Comment: i want to wrap each text and hyper link in each separate li. see this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/41s1pq3a/3/ it is nolt giving my expected output.

Comment: in loop i want to get each text and link in each iteration.

Comment: In my answer, the `$elements` is actually all of the links (`a`), and the `text` nodes..

Comment: your jsfiddle is missing the most important part of my script... https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/41s1pq3a/8/

Comment: see your jsfiddle but div is blank but we append the output to div. where is the new html modified by jquery. please let me know.

Comment: nothing getting appended to div `$('#dv').append($list);`

Comment: why blank li has been added in html `<li> </li>` ?

Comment: Empty text nodes... just filter them out inside the `.each ()`